# missing 'for' live template in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I miss 'for' live template in PhpStorm: for($i = 0 ; $i < 5 ; $i++){ ... }. - Has anybody managed to create an appropriate one? - Like 'fore' or 'forek' ?
It's very strange, that unlike Intellij IDEA there is no such official live template in PhpStorm...

Comment: So ... what problems are you having with creating it yourself?

Comment: Just trying to sort it out for a few days and simply cannot produce something working... - Would be obliged for those several lines of code.

Comment: So .. please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: I took Intellij IDEA sample from "File > Settings > Live Templates > iterations > fori":
for(int $INDEX$ = 0; $INDEX$ < $LIMIT$; $INDEX$++) {
  $END$
}
and in my attempt to adjust IDEA syntax to PhpStorm syntax (I mean 'fore' snippet in PhpStorm) - put it into PhpStorm "File > Settings > Live Templates > PHP" like this:
for(int $ITERABLE$ = 0; $ITERABLE$ < $LIMIT$; $ITERABLE$++) {
  $END$
}
No success. - I found no info on assigning / defining live templates custom variables. - So I simply don't know how to switch from built-in IDEA snippet syntax to that of PhpStorm. Thanks for patience.

Comment: Could you please 1) add template text into actual question as it looses formatting in comments 2) Show a screenshot of this template in "Settings | Live Templates" (I want to see whole settings screen and not just part of it) -- you could be missing something here. Thnx.

Comment: please look at screenshots here: http://yadi.sk/d/OKx99s87MdywU

Comment: Works just fine for me in PhpStorm v7.1.3 and v8 EAP (although in v7 I had to rearrange order of completing variables -- it used wrong one). I have modified it a bit: removed invalid "int" and remove necessity to type `$` -- http://s7.postimg.org/7rxsito1n/screen01.png . Typing `for[TAB]` works just fine. Instead of `[TAB]` -- press `Ctrl+J` to see list of all available live templates.

Comment: Thank you! It works in my PhpStorm 7.1.3 ! - At first I couldn't guess that unlike IDEA I had to start filling the newly made skeleton with 'LIMIT' and after that (by pressing 'TAB') specify 'ITERABLE' and after that (by pressing 'TAB' again) jump inside curly braces, but then I got it.

Comment: Use "Edit Variables" button to re-arrange order of variables in v7 (I have mentioned that already). v8 ordered them correctly straight away.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for digging this up, but since I've stumpled upon it coming from google, other people might as well.

The template from OP is correct. For clarity, here with nice formatting and without the leading "int":

```
for($ITERABLE$ = 0; $ITERABLE$ < $LIMIT$; $ITERABLE$++) {
    $END$
}
```

To get it to work, you have to define it as PHP template:

When defining the template in File > Settings > Live Templates, below the actual template text, there is red text: **No applicable contexts yet.**

Click on the blue "Change", set it to php and everything is fine.